# How to split table according to a column in this table?

Tags: python

Given table1 below, we cannot determine exactly how many types of `change_reason` are, but we need to split the given table into different sub tables according to different `change_reason`, for example as table 2-4. Is there a way to not filter each change reason one by one since they are different everytime and there would be a lot of new ones pop up?

table 1:

```
| Borrower | Impact |change_reason |
| -------- | -------|--------------|
| AAA      |  2.5   | ICR upgrade  |
|  BBB     |   4.0  | ICR downgrade|
|  CCC     |   5.0  | ICR upgrade  |
|  DDD     |   2.2  | New borrower |
|  EEE     |   1.0  | ICR downgrade|
...
```

table 2:

```
|Borrower | Impact | change_reason |
|---------|--------|---------------|
|  AAA    |  2.5   |  ICR upgrade  |
|  CCC    |  5.0   |  ICR upgrade  |
```

table 3:

```
|Borrower | Impact | change_reason |
|---------|--------|---------------|
| BBB     |  4.0   | ICR downgrade |
| EEE     |  1.0   | ICR downgrade |
```

table 4:

```
|Borrower | Impact | change_reason |
|---------|--------|---------------|
| DDD     |  2.2   |  New borrower |
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your issue correctly, the following code may help. tables referring to the original combined table. Create a dictionary of dataframes.

```
tables = dict(tuple(table.groupby('name')))
```

and then select as per the keys

```
tables["Change_Reason1"]
print(tables["Change_Reason2"])
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Devarshi. One further question: how to select each reason without typing the reason? Is there a systematic way to use for loop to print table with every reason directly

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code (for loop) to export the file in csv, I hope this should work. Note: table is your original dataframe

```
tables = dict(tuple(table.groupby('name')))

for key in tables.keys():
    table.loc[table["change_reason"] == key].to_csv("{}.csv".format(key), header=True)
```